# How can I set maxInvalidPasswordAttempts for a particular user role

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

In my application there are different user roles like admin, user, superuser. I am using ASP .net membership provider in my application. In my machine.config file the maxInvalidPasswordAttempts is set to 5 which is default for all users. My issue is that, even for a admin user, the maximum invalid password attempts is 5. I need to change the maximum invalid password attempts for the admin user only. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is going to be possible with the default provider.  Since the `MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts` is not even persisted in the database, as far as I can tell.  You will probably need to think about writing a derived Membership provider that implements this additional layer.

```
public class myMembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider
{

public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
{
    get
    {
        //Check to the role of the user....and pass back the attempts allowed for them

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(Admin))
        {
            return 9999; whatever...
        }
        return base.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am using a .net login control in my application. Please specify how can I use this method.

Comment: @user.net You should be able to create this class and then define it as your MembershipProvider in the web.config.  Replace `type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"` with the fully qualified name of your new custom membership provider.